# How to organize assets based on multiple layouts and render them separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails application has 3 main layouts.  I want to keep these 3 layouts separate from each in terms of their assets (images, javascript, css).

How can I organize my assets to keep them separate?

Are there any drawbacks if I just create 3 folders inside assets?
Should I create 3 folders inside of each images, javascript and stylesheets?

```
/assets/layout1/{images, javascripts, stylesheets}
/assets/layout2 ..
/assets/layout3 ..
```

or

```
/assets/images/layout1
/assets/images/layout2
..
/assets/javascripts/layout1
/assets/javascripts/layout2
..
```

In my controllers are am doing this:

```
class Layout1Controller < AC
  layout "layout1"

class Layout1Controller < AC
  layout "layout2"
```

But the problem is ALL of the javascript and css etc. gets rendering on every page.  **How can I break them out into 3 separate files?   Or is this just not possible when using the asset pipeline?**

Answer (score 2):

Check [2.2.1 Search Paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) paragraph of official guide ([The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)):

> The default locations are: the `images`, `javascripts` and `stylesheets`
>   directories under the `app/assets` folder, but these subdirectories are
>   not special - any path under `assets/*` will be searched.

So both approaches are acceptable, and which one to use is a matter of personal preference I think.

Personally the second approach is more clear to me, either way you'll end up duplicating the structure (`images`, `stylesheets`, `javascripts` inside of each `layout` directory or each `layout` inside `images`, etc.).

Comment: Sorry confused, so on each layout how do I reference the correct assets?  Currently I am getting everything i.e. all 3 sets